# Onlyfans account leaked to my family

Tags: criminal-law, police, defamation, email, stalking

I have an OnlyFans account which for obvious reasons I kept secret from everyone. But somehow someone has leaked its content (perhaps a friend or an ex-partner who wanted to take a revenge on me). He/she sent an anonymous email to my family with a link to my page. My family was shocked, my father almost had a heart attack. I went to the police (I live in the UK) and asked what could be done to investigate and potentially sue the person behind the mail. But they told me that since the link is public no law has been infringed. Is this really the case? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tell your family from me that the only one who needs to be ashamed is the lowlife who sent this message anonymously to your family. And it may be possible to examine email headers and find out who sent the message.

Comment: Was it one email with no words and only the link?

Comment: I assume your face was visible enough to the public for you to be identified. If so you were effectively performing in public.

Answer (score 4):

### What you do in public is public

There is no crime in effectively saying to another person “Hey, look at this.”

Comment: Well, unless the stuff to look at is _in itself_ illegal. I hope we can assume the OP is not a minor.

Answer (score -1):

The Crown Prosecution Service (CPS) website has guidance for prosecuting  offences related to social media and electronic communications in England and Wales.

https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/social-media-and-other-electronic-communications

The website also has guidance for prosecuting the offences of stalking and harassment.

https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/stalking-or-harassment

The circumstances described in the question don't suggest there has been a crime. For each of the relevant offences, one or more of its necessary elements do not seem to exist.

In terms of whether you could sue the sender (if you could identify them), the police can't advise you about that. You should ask Citizen's Advice or a solicitor.

It's not defamation because the information is true. Perhaps you could persuade a court that the sender 'intentionally' or 'recklessly' caused emotional distress.

Perhaps consult a solicitor - some offer a free introductory half hour of guidance otherwise it may cost a few hundred pounds for an hour of advice. They will ask you want you want to achieve.